# java.io.IOException: unexpected EOF with 512 bytes unread

Tags: tomcat, tar

i'm trying to untar a response that i get from the server , but i'm getting an exception . this is the method :

```
 public InputStream getResource(@PathParam("id") String envId, @PathParam("appName") String appName, @PathParam("imageType") String imageType,
                               @QueryParam("resourcePath") String resourcePath) throws EnvAutomationException, IOException, InterruptedException {Environment env = Envs.getEnvironmentManager().findEnvironment(envId);
    ApplicationInstance appInst = env.getApplicationInstance(appName);
    Container container = appInst.getContainer(imageType);
    InputStream resource = Envs.getContainerizationManager().getResource(container, resourcePath);    

    if (resource != null && resource.available() > 0) {
        TarInputStream myTarStream = new TarInputStream(resource);
        TarEntry entry = myTarStream.getNextEntry();
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] content = new byte[1024];
        int offset = 0;
        while ((offset = myTarStream.read(content)) > 0) {
            output.write(content, 0, offset);
        }

        output.flush();
        byte[] bo = output.toByteArray();
        InputStream lastSentValues = new ByteArrayInputStream(bo);
        return lastSentValues;
    }
    return null;

}
```

and i got this exception : `Jul 16, 2014 5:05:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [eu.eee.envs.api.JaxRsActivator] in context with path [/SQAutomationServer] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.io.IOException: unexpected EOF with 512 bytes unread] with root cause
java.io.IOException: unexpected EOF with 512 bytes unread`

```
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.tar.TarInputStream.read(TarInputStream.java:376)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.tar.TarInputStream.read(TarInputStream.java:314)
at eu.eee.envs.api.Resources.getResource(Resources.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Comment: see the answer below....

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue recently.

change this code.

```
while ((offset = myTarStream.read(content)) > 0) {
        output.write(content, 0, offset);
    }
```

to

```
   while ((offset = myTarStream.read(content,0,1024)) != -1) {
            output.write(content, 0, offset);
        }
```